# How do I access config parameters in a PHP view?

Tags: symfony

Since `sfConfig` no longer exists, how can I access config parameters from within a Symfony2 PHP view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. From within a PHP view, use this:

`$someParam = $view->container->parameters['some_param_name'];`

On a side note, to keep my app specific params organized, I store them in app/config/app.yml, then include this file into the config.yml. The config.yml can get pretty crowded, so I think it makes sense to keep your params in a separate location.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what config values are you grabbing in the config?

Comment: Custom ones, in this case. If they were in config.yml, they'd be under the 'parameters' block. Think of it like how you'd access app.yml settings in Symfony 1

Answer (score 0):

In newer Symfony2 versions (tested it in 2.3) this is:

```
$view->container->getParameter('some_param_name')
```

The parameter attribute was made private.